# Poisson Variable $P(X \le 2)$ - is there a better way?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

> Let $X$ be a poisson variable with $\lambda=2$. Calculate $P(X\le 2)$.

Is there a better way for calculating this rather than the following?

$$P(X \le 2)=P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)$$

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Thanks, wanted to be sure.